# Could not find stored procedure 'LOGPARSER'

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008

I installed Microsoft LogParser v2.2, it's on my machine, but this is what i'm getting when i run it:

```
       Msg 2812, Level 16, State 62, Line 1
       Could not find stored procedure 'LOGPARSER'.
```

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: What did you type to get this message?  BTW, LogParser is not related to SQL Server (other than using an SQL-like language).  If you are trying to use it from SQL Server, then that's your problem.

Comment: I just typed LOGPARSER.. I was trying some other examples i found online and was just getting errors.. So i'm thinking SQL 2008 isn't even noticing i have it installed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

LogParser does not run in SQL Server.  It is a separate program.  You run it from the command line.  Here are some usage [examples](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee692659.aspx) from Microsoft.

It does use a SQL syntax, but it has nothing to do with SQL Server.

Comment: oh i saw the cmd prompt for it, so i guess i have to use this for it?  i thought you can run it from New Query.

Answer (score 0):

You say you installed it, Is this a software that installs a database or did you just added it to your Database?

Is your connection string pointing to that server?

Comment: i just installed it from ms site, i would assume when i open SQL 2008 > New Query , and run it, it would notice it, am i wrong? do i have to do something else first?

Comment: Yes, when you open it up it might end up in the master database. Make sure that the Query window is connected to your database.

Comment: yea, it was on the master, let me create a new db and test that out.. will post results.

Comment: well i ran it on the new db i just made, instead of master, and it still gives this error.

Comment: Can you actually see the Stored Procedure under the Stored Procedures folder in your SQL Management Studio? Programmability > Stored Procedures > LOGPARSER